# Differential of a matrix function: $f:\mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ $f(A) = A^T\cdot \vec{v}$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, differential

I wish to calculate the differential of a function: $f(A) = X^T\cdot \vec{v}$ when $A\in  \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with respect to $A$.

Since this is a linear function, if we think about $D\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ as a direction we suppose to get $f(A) + \nabla_A f \cdot D = f(A+D)$ since there are no non-linear terms. If we think about $f(A+D), f(A)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}, D\in \mathbb{R}^{(n\times m) \times 1}$ we learn that $\nabla f_A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times (n\times m)}$. Thus $\nabla_A f\cdot D\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$.

My question though is how should we define the multiplication $\mathbb{R}^{m \times (n \times m)} \cdot \mathbb{R}^{(n\times m)\times 1}$?. we need kind of a matrix multiplication which results in a scalar i.e $(n\times m) \oplus (n\times m) \in \mathbb{R}$. But what this operation needs to be? and how this operation represent the idea of differensial?

I put here a related question, asked 5 years ago which was not answered. [Differntiating matrix functions $f : \mathbb R^{n\times m} \to \mathbb R^{p\times q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268505/differntiating-matrix-functions-f-mathbb-rn-times-m-to-mathbb-rp-time)

Comment: Is the "differential" of a function with respect to $A$ different from the "derivative" of a function with respect to $A$?

Comment: In terms of the ["total derivative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), we might say that 
$$
df(A)(H) = f(H) = H^T v.
$$
If you prefer, you could also think of $df(A)$ as a type $(2,1)$ [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor). It is not clear what you mean by the "multiplication of such objects".

Comment: It might help if you explain **why** we need a matrix multiplication which results in a scalar. What is it that you want to use this multiplication for?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't fully get your last question since in order for this multiplication to be well defined the matrices multiplication must result in a scalar so the whole multiplication's dimension ends up $\mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$

Comment: Upon rereading, I understand that you're talking specifically about multiplying the arrays $\nabla_A f$ and $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the transpose of your function, and with the help of the Kronecker product, [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) it to obtain a linear equation whose gradient is trivial to calculate.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(f^T) &= {\rm vec}(v^TA) \\
   &= \left(I_m\otimes v^T\right){\rm vec}(A) \\
 f &= \left(I_m\otimes v^T\right)a \\
df &= \left(I_m\otimes v^T\right)da \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
 &= \left(I_m\otimes v^T\right)
 \;=\; G \quad&({\rm the\,gradient\,matrix}) \\
}$$
The index mapping between $a$ and $A$ components is tedious but straightforward
$$\eqalign{
A &\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times m} \implies
a \in {\mathbb R}^{mn\times 1} \\
A_{ij} &= a_k \\
k &= i+(j-1)\,n \\
i &= 1+(k-1)\,{\rm mod}\,n \\
j &= 1+(k-1)\,{\rm div}\,n \\
}$$
and can be used to calculate the components of the 3rd-order gradient tensor
$$\eqalign{
\Gamma_{pij}
 &= \frac{\partial f_p}{\partial A_{ij}}
 &= \frac{\partial f_p}{\partial a_k}
 &= G_{pk}
\\
}$$
The [derivative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Derivatives_of_tensor-valued_functions_of_second-order_tensors) $\big($in the direction of $D\,\big)$ that you are seeking is 
$$\eqalign{
df &= f(A+D)-f(A) \\
&= \Gamma:D &({\rm in\,product\,form}) \\
df_{p} &= \Gamma_{pij}\,D_{ij} &({\rm in\,component\,form}) \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the double-dot product 
$\big($and assuming $\|D\|_F^2\ll 1\big)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the terminology that I applied to your [old question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1268505/81360).

Let $f_i$ denote the function whose output is the $i$th entry of $f(A)$. Let $e_i$ denote the $i$th standard basis vector. We have
$$
f_i(A) = e_i^TA^Tv = \operatorname{tr}([ve_i^T]^TA) \implies\\
df_i(A)(H) = \operatorname{tr}([ve_i^T]^TH), \quad 
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial A} = v e_i^T.
$$
So, the directional derivative of $f_i$ along $D$ will be given by 
$$
\operatorname{tr}([v e_i^T]^TD) = v^TD e_i = e_i^TD^Tv = \sum_{k=1}^n v_k d_{ki}.
$$

In other words, we should find in the end that 
$$
\nabla_A f \cdot D = \pmatrix{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k d_{k1}\\ \vdots \\ \sum_{k=1}^n v_k d_{kn}} = D^T v.
$$
That said, this derivation doesn't directly tell us how to generally multiply arrays of the shape.

---

Extending the above logic, if the "frontal slice" $[\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}_{j,k,i}]_{j,k=1}^{n,m}$ is the denominator-form derivative of $f_i:\Bbb R^{n \times m} \to \Bbb R^n$, then the "directional derivative" along $D$ is given by
$$
[\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} \cdot D]_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m 
\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}\right]_{jki} d_{jk}.
$$